# Custom Blocks Problems GNU RADIO

Tags: python, usrp, gnuradio-companion

I'm having some problems with my flowgraph in GNU Radio. I built a custom block to be a Delay block because the native block didn't work very well for my application. Before my custom block there is a UHD Source. It's working in a sample rate of 4M. However when I start my simulation it is generating overflows ("O"). I think this is strange because when I save in a file the output of UHD source and then play again the simulation in mode "off-line" there isn't errors of overflow.  In the other words, I have problems just when I am working in mode "on-line". Only when I'm working with UHD Source and not a file saved before by UHD Source.

[image]

### Delay_amostra_sync block code:

import numpy

from gnuradio import gr

class Delay_amostra_sync(gr.sync_block):
    """
    docstring for block Delay_amostra_sync
    """
    def **init**(self, var):
        gr.sync_block.**init**(self,
            name="Delay_amostra_sync",
            in_sig=[numpy.complex64],
            out_sig=[numpy.complex64])
        self.var = var
        self.cont = 0
        self.buffer = numpy.array([])
        self.c = 1

```
def work(self, input_items, output_items):
    in0 = input_items[0]
    out = output_items[0]

    self.dados = numpy.array(input_items[0], copy=True)

    self.buffer = numpy.append(self.buffer, self.dados)      

    if self.cont >= self.var:                         
        out[:] = self.buffer[range(0,len(out))]
        self.buffer = numpy.delete(self.buffer, range(0,len(out)), 0)            
    self.cont = self.cont + 1
```

### return len(output_items[0])

Comment: So, your custom block is too slow.

Comment: So, what does your custom block do that the original delay block did not? Explaining that and analyzing why your block is too slow is the solution to your problem.

Comment: Clean up grammar.

Comment: Thanks for your attention @MarcusMüller . I follow the Stackoverflow website and appreciate your contribuitions to others users in this area of RF.
I am working in a company that develop solutions to IoT. My area is SDR. 
Currently we are working with WiSUN. My flowgraph should identificate some channels in a range of frequency and next send to the filter the central frequency. To this i need delay the signal before the filter because when my "identificator" find some frequency the signal can't pass througth it.

Comment: I dindn't know why the native delay block dont work. So i decided to build a delay custom block.

The problem is that this custom block is generating "overflow". A interesting observation is that when i decreased the sample rate to 2M it didn't generate "overflows". I will change to a computer that have a lot of memory to check if this is a problem(memory).

Comment: PS: I put a photo to help understand the problem @MarcusMüller.

Comment: If the stock delay block didn't work for you, then that means you're expecting it to do something that it doesn't. That's what I asked you: what does *your* block do.

Comment: The block "Delay_amostra_sync" stores in a buffer the signal of input until the counter   reaches a value especificated by user. This will cause a delay that is enough to the "Wisun_process" block to have indentificate a channel. So after my filter is configred rigtly i can demodulate my packet of data.

Comment: PS: I put the code of Delay_amostra_sync block above